# The greatest eigenvalue of a vector multiplied by its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A = XX^T$ be an $n \times n$ matrix where $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$

I know that $\|X\|^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, but is it the greatest one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is the greatest one, the others are $0$: the rank of the matrix is $1$.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help

Comment: The matrix has rank $1$ or $0$  (all rows are proportional to $X^T$). The Jordan form $J$ has the same rank. This only can happen when all Jordan blocks are of size $1$ and at most one eigenvalue is $\ne 0$.

Comment: The nonzero eigenvalue must be $|X|^2$ (a corresponding eigenvector is $X$).

Answer (score 1):

If $A= u v^T$ then a little work with Sylvester's determinant identity gives $\det(\lambda I -uv^T) = \lambda^{n-1}(\lambda-v^Tu)$.

Hence $A$ has $n-1$ eigenvalues at zero and one at $v^Tu$.

In the above case, this is $X^TX =\|X\|^2$.